# What is the consensus regarding the term "gliding vowel"?

Tags: terminology, diphthongs, glides

I write educational resources about Japanese. In my explanations, I try to avoid using overly technical terms so as to avoid scaring my readers, who tend to be people without a linguistic background.

I think many people who have studied a foreign language have probably heard the term "diphthong" before, but I'd wager that not many casual learners actually understand clearly what it is. For that reason, I've taken to using the term "gliding vowel" and illustrating what it is by using the English "long o" sound.

From my searching online, it appears that "gliding vowel" is an accepted synonym for "diphthong." I prefer the term "gliding vowel" because it is possible for an uninitiated person to instantly imagine what it probably means. The term is clear and memorable.

The possible critique I can see against this term is that it is similar to "glide," which I do understand indicates something different. (And, full disclosure, in the past, I have incorrectly have called gliding vowels glides, an error I am correcting as I revise my materials.)

I am trying to strike a balance between technical accuracy and approachability. Is "gliding vowel" a term that a linguist would take issue with?

Comment: In my circles, we use _gliding vowel_ to refer to a vowel _phone_ with distinct beginning and ending formant values, and we reserve the term _diphthong_ for a vowel _phoneme_ that comprises two separate vowel phones. So we would call the typical English "long o sound" a gliding vowel and the English phoneme /aj/ (as in _high_) a diphthong. But this distinction is probably not widely recognized.

Comment: I would use _gliding_ to refer to an intonation, not a formant or an offglide. You have to be careful searching for linguistic terms online; don't be certain that it's "accepted", except by some people in some meanings in some contexts. There's nothing wrong with _diphthong_ -- it's a name for a vowel cluster of one kind or another. It's no more technical than _consonant_ or _vowel_, except it's spelled funny. But it's pronounced easily -- /dɪpθɔŋ/ -- so it wouuld only be three syllables in Japanese.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! 

The "long o" is actually the only sound I want to draw attention to, mainly because it is less obvious than a sound like the "long a" that there are multiple components in it, and the Japanese "o" definitely does not contain this glide to an "ooh." So it sounds like "gliding vowel" is okay here.

@jlawler, I certainly don't think there's anything *wrong* with "diphthong," but since they don't exist in Japanese and the discussion is only to point out something to notice and avoid, I wanted to avoid using a funny sounding word that few non-experts understand.

Comment: Then call them vowel clusters. You certainly have to talk about consonant clusters; there are so many of them in English.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! So, to be sure I understand, is the term *vowel cluster* broad enough to encompass both gliding vowels and diphthongs (using @musiciallinguist's differentiation) and perhaps even semivowels?

Comment: To say (as our friend musicallinguist does) that the vowel in "high" is a diphthong, while that in "low" is a mere "gliding vowel" is a totally artificial distinction.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more precise. What I meant was that in my line of work, in the dialect of English that is the object of my study (and probably some others), it is useful to distinguish between the two cases I mentioned because they are subject to different phonetic processes. That said, I'm not sure what kind of distinction @fdb would consider to be a "natural" distinction.

Comment: So, @fdb, am I correct in understanding that for you, the terms *diphthong* and *gliding vowel* are synonymous?

Comment: @jlawler "so it wouuld only be three syllables in Japanese", what do you mean by that? Japanese has its own word for diphthong 二重母音, which I believe is 4 syllables in standard analysis.

Comment: @dainichi: If Japanese borrowed _diphthong_, as English speakers pronounce it, it would probly come out as /di.pu.ton/, three syllables. The intrusive vowel in the middle syllable might be different, but I'll guess /u/. That's all I meant. I rather expected that Japanese has its own word, but for some reason the spelling of the English word makes some people think it's too complex a concept for students to understand. I think that's silly.

Comment: @jlawler, the common rules for English loan words in Japanese would yield /di.fu.soN.gu/, 4 syllables and 5 morae. http://www.japanlink.co.jp/dtpjiten/te/diphthong.html